# Cannot create a new user in Amazon Redshift using SQL Workbench/J

Tags: amazon-redshift

I have a problem with creating a new user in Amazon Redshift. I followed the description on [Getting Started with Amazon Redshift](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/gsg/getting-started.html) and was able to create a cluster with data from the example described there. I can connect to the cluster using the latest version of SQL Workbench/J (Build 122, 2017-02-04) and of the driver (JDBC 4.2–compatible) from an EC2 instance. It fails when I try to create a new user:

```
create user dbuser25x with password 'abcD1234';
```

One of these things happens:

1. I get the message confirming that the user was created, but there is no user:

   ```
   User dbuser25x created
   Execution time: 0.04s
   ```
2. The query fails:

   ```
   An error occurred when executing the SQL command:
   create user dbuser25x with password 'abcD1234'
   [Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: user "dbuser25x" already exists;
   1 statement failed.
   Execution time: 0s
   ```
3. The query hangs.

In every situation I use this statement to check the result:

```
    select * from pg_user;
```

This user is not there and I do not know why.

Another developer tried to create a new user in the same way and got the same problems.
I tried solutions from the section There Is a Potential Deadlock of [Troubleshooting Queries](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/queries-troubleshooting.html) - they did not help.
I used a dedicated Windows EC2 instance on which I installed only SQL Workbench/J to exclude influence of other software - this did not solve the problem.

Comment: Aside from not appearing in `pg_user`, are you able to actually login as that user?

Comment: I have just tried. Unfortunately, I could not connect.Thanks for the hint.

Comment: I get the message: Connection failed. [Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: password authentication failed for the user "dbuser25x";

Comment: If you try and connect with a different (non-existent) username, does it give the same error? That will tell whether the username is being recognised.

Comment: The error message is the same. Thanks for this tip.

Comment: Did you `commit` the `create user` statement?

Comment: Yes, I tried it yesterday. It did not work. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works fine for me:

```
create user dbuser25x with password 'abcD1234';

select * from pg_user;

rdsdb         1 true    true    true    ********    infinity    (null)
masteruser  100 true    true    false   ********    (null)  (null)
dbuser25x   101 false   false   false   ********    (null)  (null)
```

Comment: I ran both queries about 15 minutes ago and succeeded. I was able to add 3 more users and could see all of them in the table pg_user. Then suddenly the query for the forth user hung. I run the query 'select * from pg_user;' and none of the four users is there.I can't make any sense of this.

Comment: I wonder if it is related to auto-commit? I don't think transactions apply against `CREATE USER`, but you can try it. Just turn on the "autocommit" checkbox when establishing a connection with Redshift.

Comment: It works right now and it wonders me. I tried yesterday to run the command `commit` and it did not work. And as I understand "autocommit" when establishing a connection is equivalent to `commit` after each SQL statement. For this reason I want to work with it for a while to see if it solves the problem, and then to close the question.

Answer (score 2):

Had the same problem, as the comment by Chris (above) says, I had to `commit` the `create user` opperation. In SQL Workbench/J there is "Commit" button in your tool bar, I guess you can just type in the `commit` command as well.

Comment: Thank you, I had this exact same problem that the user was never created because I was running my DB tool with manual transaction management.